# Unable to understand a syntax in python

Tags: python

I am new to python.I was analyzing some code snippets to realize how far I've come,to check if I had missed some key concepts of python and I got stuck here(a part of a keylogger program).

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    #statements...
    return True

hookMgr = pyHook.HookManager()       
hookMgr.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent     # stuck here!
```

OnKeyboardEvent is an identifier for a function right?And to call functions we should have done like:

```
hookMgr.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent(some_argument)
```

My question is Why no parenthesis and arguments were used?Is this some different concept that I dont know?

I even tried to analyze what had happened doing this:

```
def foo(var):
  return True

ires = foo
if ires == True:
  print 'done'
```

It printed nothing.So does it mean identifier 'foo' as a function and 'foo' as a variable are different?

Comment: If you know C, it's like a function pointer; it's setting the `hookMgr.KeyDown` attribute to point at the `OnKeyboardEvent` function, so when a `KeyDown` action is required, `OnKeyboardEvent` will be called.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay but why does the code in second part of this Question (containing 'foo') does not work? And whats the point  of 'function pointer' here?There aren't pointers in python...

Comment: Everything is an object in Python. This includes functions. A `def` just assigns a function object to a variable of the function name in the current scope. It can even be reassigned like any other variable, and like any other variable, its value can be assigned to another variable as well.

Comment: Try `if ires() == True:` instead, and you'll see that `ires = foo` simply bound the reference `ires` to the same function as `foo`.

Comment: The use of `ires` in `if ires == True:` does not invoke the function that `ires` references.  You'd need to use: `if ires() == True:` — that does then print "done".  The reference held in `ires` is not the same as the reference for True.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  it didn't work.And whats the point of 'function pointer' here?We could have just called the function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `OnKeyboardEvent` is a reference to the function itself, while `OnKeyboardEvent()` is a reference to the result of calling the function. `hookMgr.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent` connects `hookMgr.KeyDown` to the given function, similarly to the way `tkinter.Button(command=myfunction)` would connect a function, not the value returned by a function call, to a Tkinter button.

Comment: In my Q, hookMgr.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent is just a reference to OnKeyboardEvent() right?I haven't called the function anywhere but it works.why?

Comment: @Kishor - No, it's not a reference to `OnKeyboardEvent()`. That would be the value returned by calling the function `OnKeyboardEvent`. It is a reference to the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd show you some example which I believe will help you to understand this Python's feature.

```
def calc(func, a, b):
    return func(a, b)

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

print(calc(add, 2, 2))  # 4
print(calc(sub, 42, 1))  # 41
```

That's it. You can pass some function as argument of the other function, or store it in some variable and then call it etc. It's really useful, but a bit unusual.

By the way, my favorite usage of this feature: using dictionary with functions instead of (missing) `switch .. case` operator. Like this:

```
def get_serialized_value(obj):
    serializer = {
        Article: article_brief_serialize,
        RichTextArticle: rich_text_article_brief_serialize,
        Gallery: gallery_serialize
    }.get(type(obj))
    return serializer(obj).data if serializer else None

# what was replaced by the code above..
def get_serialized_value(obj):
    if type(obj) == Article:
        return article_brief_serialize(obj)
    elif type(obj) == RichTextArticle:
        return rich_text_article_brief_serialize(obj)
    elif type(obj) == Gallery:
        return gallery_serialize(obj)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: okay but in my Q, hookMgr.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent  is just a reference to OnKeyboardEvent() right?I havent called the function anywhere but it works.why?

Comment: Somewhere in code it's called (I guess somewhere in the class you instantiated). Thanks to Python's flexibility, you can easily assign function to be called on event or even class which will handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

A great thing about python is that functions and classes are themselves objects, and can thus be passed around as variables. For example, a function that has another function as an argument could be something like

```
def foo(bar):
    bar()
```

In which you can call it and input the name of any function, and it will call the function you input with no arguments. Often this is used in event handler models, where you will pass an object a reference to a function, and when an event happens, the object will call your function, which is what is happening in your called.